# while executing procprob, does b can be any data type?

Tags: c, assembly, types, x86-64, reverse-engineering

c code :

```
 *u +=a;
 *v +=b;
 return sizeof(a)+ sizeof(b);
```

x86-64 code:

```
movslq %edi, %rdi
addq %rdi, (%rdx)
addb %sil, (%rcx)
movl $6 %eax
ret
```

I know that movl $6 %eax means 2+4(or 4+2) and one is int and the other is short.

But when we think that ignoring movl $6 %eax, b can be any data types such as 1 ,2, 4 and 8 bytes of the data type. I have a question about this.

1. Let's assume b is long (**Of course, we ignore movl $6 %eax**) Does the assembly for b being %sil means b has only 1 byte data and remaining 7 bytes has only zero? Give me some examples when it is okay for b to have %sil register(1-byte register) even though b is long data type(8 bytes register)

Comment: `addq %sil, (%rcx)` is technically not correct AT&T syntax, because "q" suffix indicates 64 bit operand, but `sil` is only 8 bits. So it's not obvious how the compiler will treat it. Also why it does then do `mov $6, %eax` if the `b` is `short`, yet `add` is using `char`... seems like the assembly was patched by hand and it's not result of C compiler? Or can you show [MCVE] of the C source which does produce such assembly, and with which compiler+options? Anyway, about your Q, if I understand it correctly (it's not very clear): if you need 32/64b type, then `sil` is not correct. It's never ok.

Comment: actually it may be okay, if the pointer `v` is `char*`-like type, then it's ok to add only 8 bits of larger value, that's like `*v += (char)b;` ... that's of course valid assembly then (but there would be `addb`, not `addq` in AT&T syntax).

Comment: How are all variables defined? Is `v` a uint8_t?

Comment: @Ped7g: no, it's not legal.  `foo.s:1: Error: '%sil' not allowed with 'addq'`.  This question makes no sense, because it looks like you're given this code and supposed to reverse-engineer the C types, but the asm is invalid so it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the assembly for `b` being `%sil` mean `b` has only 1 byte data and remaining 7 bytes has only zero?

No, it means that `*v` (in memory) is only 1 byte long.  Any bytes after that are not part of the object pointed to by `v` at all.  (**It has a different size than `b`.**)

If you're supposed to reverse-engineer the types of `a` and `b` from the asm: notice that it's sizeof `a` and `b`, not sizeof `*u` and `*v`.  The operand-size of the `add` instructions matches `sizeof(*u)` and `sizeof(*v)`, and the source operands for those are the result of C integer promotion / conversion rules being applied to `a` and `b`.

e.g. `l += s` is like `l += (long)s` if we have `long l; short s;`

---

**If the `addq` was confusing you, don't worry, that's invalid with a byte register.  Trying to assemble that with GAS (`gcc -c foo.s`) gives:**

```
foo.s:1: Error: `%sil' not allowed with `addq'
```

---

**If we assume that it's actually `addb %sil, (%rcx)`  instead of an illegal `addq`, then the question is answerable.**

Assuming the C statements are in the same order as the asm instructions (the compiler chose not to reorder them), then this looks like code from a function signature like this, compiled for the x86-64 System V ABI, so args are in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX in that order.

```
int f(TYPEA a, TYPEB b, TYPEU *u, TYPEV *v);
```

TYPEA and TYPEU are *not* the same type, which we can already tell because 8 > 6 so any qword type doesn't fit, and the fact that sign-extension was needed.

A dword `a` is *sign*-extended to qword.  So `a` is a 32-bit signed integer type.  In x86-64 System V, only `int` meets that description out of the basic types.  `long` is 64-bit, `short` is 16-bit.  (In Windows x64, `long` is also a 32-bit type, but this smells like x86-64 System V from the choice of registers.) 
 `int32_t` is defined in terms of `int`, on gcc, in case you want to think about it in terms of the fixed-width types.

If it had been `movswq %di, %rdi`, we'd have `int16_t a` (or `short a`).  It there had been no sign-extension, then we'd know it was one of `int64_t a` or `uint64_t a`.

(`*u` is either `uint64_t` or `int64_t`; we don't know which.  `(unsigned long long)(int)x;` sign-extends to the width of `unsigned long long`.

---

Your 6 = 2+4 logic is correct.  The other type is definitely 16-bit = 2 bytes, because `char` is 1 byte in x86-64 System V so sizeof sizes are in bytes.  And no mainstream ABI has 5-byte integer types.

`short` is a 16-bit type; so is `unsigned short`.  We can't uniquely determine which it is.

We're inferring it *only* from the size: any wider or smaller integer type added to an `int8_t` will be truncated to the width.  (Signed overflow here might actually be undefined behaviour in C, I forget.  When compiled for x86-64, **the resulting asm behaves the way you'd expect and only takes the low byte of whatever integer type it was.**)

---

**Compiling this [with clang 7.0 -O3 (on the Godbolt compiler explorer)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.0749542399999998,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'typedef+int+TYPEA%3B%0Atypedef+short+TYPEB%3B%0Atypedef+long+TYPEU%3B%0Atypedef+char+TYPEV%3B%0A%0Aint+f(TYPEA+a,+TYPEB+b,+TYPEU+*u,+TYPEV+*v)+%7B%0A+++++*u+%2B%3Da%3B%0A+++++*v+%2B%3Db%3B%0A+++++return+sizeof(a)%2B+sizeof(b)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+sign-extension+doesn!'t+prove+that+the+target+type+is+signed,%0A//+only+that+the+source+type+is+signed.%0Aunsigned+long+long+sign_extend(int+x)+%7B%0A++++return+(unsigned+long+long)(int)x%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:44.355909694555116,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:28.061203133977937,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:27.582887171466954,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)** gives almost *exactly* the asm you show in the question (except with `addb` instead of `addq`).  gcc puts the `mov`-immediate earlier in the function, which possibly lets the function decode in fewer clock cycles, or at least the `mov` decode a cycle earlier, along with one of the 2-fused-domain-uop memory-destination add instructions.

```
typedef int TYPEA;
typedef short TYPEB;
typedef long TYPEU;
typedef char TYPEV;

int f(TYPEA a, TYPEB b, TYPEU *u, TYPEV *v) {
     *u +=a;
     *v +=b;
     return sizeof(a)+ sizeof(b);
}
```

```
# clang -O3 output
f:                                      # @f
    movslq  %edi, %rax           # clang uses RAX instead of extending into the same register
    addq    %rax, (%rdx)         # no difference in effect.
    addb    %sil, (%rcx)
    movl    $6, %eax
    retq
```

Of course, `unsigned char` or `unsigned long` for the pointer types give the same asm.  Or `unsigned long long`, which is also a 64-bit type.

But more importantly, `unsigned short b` would also give the same asm.

Comment: I don’t understand what the second paragraph is supposed to mean—C integer promotions don’t apply to the operand of sizeof.

Comment: Simply I mean that is it right when, for example, b is a 0xabcdefff. Then %b is truncated (since it is just 1-byte register %sil)? Is it okay???

Comment: @prl: Thanks for letting me know it was confusing.  Rewritten to express what I was thinking, I hope.

Comment: @KFC: Yes, exactly.  `*v += 0xabcdefff` is equivalent to `*v += 0xff` because the right hand side is truncated to 1 byte to match the size of `*v`.